# Python Time Series 2.0

Tags: python

I am working on a real estate cashflow forecast and the end result needs to be an excel file with rents and the date rent was perceived. 
The problem that I am facing is the downtime between tenants. Let's say there is a 2 weeks downtime, the new tenant will not be paying rent on the first but on the 15th. This is the part of the code giving me troubles :

```
rng=pd.date_range('1/1/2016', '1/2/2016', freq='MS' )
(...) 
rng=rng.union(pd.date_range(start=start , periods=leasing, freq='MS')+pd.DateOffset(days=shift))
```

The problem I have, using an example, is that I get the new rent due on the 15th of January (so far so good) but because of shifting the next payments are not on the 15th but they range from the 14th to the 17th. I need them to be on the month. Is there a better way to use the .shift()?